# Shorthand if not running or evaluating

Tags: php, input, shorthand-if

I'm basically checking a users download limit in my database, and if their limit is `< 1` I want to disable a input on my page.

```
<input type="text" name="link"<?php ($page["downloads_left"] < 1 ? " disabled=\"1\"" : ""); ?> />
```

When the page is run, the input is not disabled and I don't have any `disabled="1"` markup on my page. I have verified that `$page["downloads_left"]` is less than 1, and it is. It's 0.

Even when I add a string to be outputted if this IF statement evaluates false, it doesn't show in the markup.

Can anyone provide any help? Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place an echo in the line:

```
<input type="text" name="link"<?php echo ($page["downloads_left"] < 1 ? " disabled=\"1\"" : ""); ?> />
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget the `echo` after `<?php`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to echo it

```
<?php echo ($page['downloads_left'] < 1) ? " disabled='1' " : ''?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<?php ($page...`

should be

`<?php echo ($page...`